# Autosize Spreadsheet Columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I didn't see anything in the documentation that would make me think this is a supported function.  I'm writing to several sheets and visually it's difficult to see all the data without highlighting all the columns and autosizing with my mouse.  I'd rather not have to do that everytime I run my script.

Is there a way to do this programmatically with app scripts?  I saw the option to setColumnWidth, but how do I know how wide to set my columns when my text could vary from column to column.

==thanks for any help.

Answer (score 9):

`autoResizeColumn(columnPosition)`

See [the API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#autoResizeColumn%28Integer%29) for more details

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work as expected. I still have some columns that are just wrapped.

Answer (score 5):

There is now a new method called `autoResizeColumn(columnPosition)`

```
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
s.autoResizeColumn(6);
```

Autosizes the 6th column (a.k.a column "F").

See this stackoverflow answer
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/29930315/8458041

---

There's also a way to do multiple columns at once: `autoResizeColumns(startColumn, numColumns)`

```
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();        
s.autoResizeColumns(6, 3);
```

Autosizes columns F, G, and H.

---

The corresponding autosizing method for multiple rows is `autoResizeRows(startRow, numRows)`

```
s.autoResizeRows(6, 3);
```

Autosizes rows 6, 7, and 8

There is no corresponding single-row autosizing method ([yet?](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#autoresizerowsstartrow,-numrows)); to autosize a single row, specify 1 for the number of rows

```
s.autoResizeRows(6, 1);
```

Autosizes only row 6

Comment: is there a way to set a minimal width for autoResize? or to do function which will decide if to use autoResize or absolute width setup?

Answer (score 1):

Now there is no ability to auto-size spreadsheet columns widths from a GAS. There is a [topic](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1743) in the issue tracker about it. Please star this topic to demonstrate 
Google that many people require this feature.

Comment: thanks for the info.  I followed your suggestion and starred the topic.  #best.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work when trying to iterate through a specified number of columns and autosizing based on the width of the text in the column:

```
 for (var i = 1; i < 9; i ++){ sheet.autoResizeColumn(i);}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you disable wrapping on the cells in your range you can achieve the desired affect.

Here's a snippet that worked for me:

```
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(1,1,data.length,headers.length);
dataRange.setValues(data);
dataRange.setWrap(false);
```

Goolge Apps Documentation:
[Range.setWrap](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range#setWrap)

Comment: setWrap still not affected to selected column.