# Automatically resize columns in Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to have columns on google sheets automatically resize to fit my text, without me having to manually resize them after every entry. How do I do this?

Answer (score 30):

FYI -- For those who don't want to delve into scripting, but want a way to do it faster, you can auto-resize all the columns at once, manually: Hit Cmd+A (or Ctrl+A in Windows) to select everything, then move the mouse to the border between any two column headers -- as if you wanted to resize that one manually-- the cursor changes to an arrow... and *double click*.  Found this trick [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/aJY5xhEo4Kw).

Comment: I just tried this and it didn't work on a Mac. Seems like just pressing `Cmd+A` doesn't select the whole sheets, just every cell where content is present. To select the whole sheet you can either klick on the grey square at the top left corner of the sheet (left of column A and top of row 1) or you select a cell outside your content, and then press `Cmd+A`

Comment: Thanks, yes, the way in which Google Sheets selects all seems to be a little... mysterious.  For example, it seems like hitting `Cmd+A` once is different from hitting it twice in a row.  (Twice is more like "yes, I really mean it" and turns the headers grey and really seems to select _everything_.)  In general, the resize trick works on the column you are on (i.e., you click its header's rightmost border while the cursor is a right-facing arrow).

Comment: Once selects all of the data. Twice selects all of the columns with that data. You have to have the column selected (column headers should be dark gray with white text) for this to work. Otherwise double-clicking only changes the one column to the left of the edge you clicked.

Comment: This did not work for me in on Google Chrome, Mac OSX, 2021...

Answer (score 11):

Sounds like you want [autoResizeColumn](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#autoResizeColumn%28Integer%29). Make an AppScript script and you can put

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

sheet.autoResizeColumn(COLUMN_NUMBER);
```

Which will resize the specified column based off its contents.

Run the function everytime you want to resize or put it in a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) like onOpen().

However, it seems to have a maximum size that it will change to.

Answer (score 6):

To make the column re-size fully automatic you an create this function, which will trigger every time you edit the contents of a cell:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.range.getSheet ().autoResizeColumn (e.range.getColumn ());
}
```

Note that this trigger will only run in response to typing.  Pasting and importing will not cause this trigger to run.

If you want a function that will resize all columns in your active sheet, this one will do it:

```
function resizeAllColumns () {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var firstColumn = dataRange.getColumn();
  var lastColumn = dataRange.getLastColumn();
  sheet.autoResizeColumns(firstColumn, lastColumn);
}
```

For convenience you can attach a keyboard shortcut to the function if you need to execute the manual function often.

Answer (score 3):

FYI, I don't know an automatic method. But you can do it at once by:

- selecting desired columns from their `headers`
- `right-click` anywhere on the `selected area`
- Select `Resize columns......` part from the menu
- Select `Fit to Data`
- Click `OK`

And you are done.

Comment: [I don't see any "Resize Colums......." part on the menu](https://i.snipboard.io/urbXhE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

first of all, select the desired cells and then right-click on it(on the left side of the sheet, where numbers are written), choose the "resize cell" option from the GUI, and then select "fit to data" and click on ok button.