# PHP SpreadSheet can't find the function to auto size column width

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I simply want the columns to autosized. I am using php spreadsheet and I can't find how to do it. Any advise ? This is my code

```
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Projects First Year');
$sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Grades');

$sheet->setCellValue('A2', 'PHP Project 2020');
$sheet->setCellValue('B2', $_SESSION['phpScore']);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381875/autosize-spreadsheet-columns

Comment: @Dezigo this is phpexcel not spreadsheet anyway thnx ..but i found it

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Don't use range(). It won't work when cells beyond Z.
Use instead

```
foreach ($sheet->getColumnIterator() as $column) {
   $sheet->getColumnDimension($column->getColumnIndex())->setAutoSize(true);
}
```

Answer (score 13):

For spreadsheet the answer is:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

  foreach (range('A','B') as $col) {
   $sheet->getColumnDimension($col)->setAutoSize(true);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A slight modification that does not require you to know how many columns you have in your spreadsheet:

```
foreach (range('A', $sheet->getHighestColumn()) as $col) {
   $sheet->getColumnDimension($col)->setAutoSize(true);
}
```

Comment: for some reason when highest column beyond than z, setAutosize(true) is not woking

Comment: That's right! I also found this out and should have corrected my comment!

Comment: That's because `range()` only looks at the first character of the strings. In current PHP versions this code now emits a warning.